# Update UI without freezing

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable, grid-layout

I have a `GridLayout` with several buttons in it.

I need to change the color of each button in a sequence, let's say, every 3 seconds.

I am having a problem over here... Take a look at my code:

```
runnableScan = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        GridLayout view = Grid;
        for ( int i = 0; i < view.getChildCount(); i++) {
            Button btn = (Button)view.getChildAt(i);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            handlerScan.postDelayed(this, 3000);                                        
        }
    }
};      
handlerScan.postDelayed(runnableScan, 3000);
```

Well.. it does change the color of all buttons to red, but it changes them **all at once**!!!

I wanted it to change the colors in a sequence, one button every 3 seconds.

If I put a `Toast` inside there, the `Toast` will be fired every three seconds with the index of each button.

What I am doing wrong? Why are all buttons being changed to red at once??

Comment: Are you sure that the `Toast` is getting ran every 3 seconds and you are not seeing it until after the previous `Toast` is dismissed?

Comment: Judge from the code you've posted, it is actually changing all the buttons color at once. Try replacing toast with Log.d and compare the timing with the logcat entries again. Toast may give you an illusion of delay because second toast will not appear until first toast is cleared.

Comment: Hello codeMagic and TactMayers! Thank you for your feedback. In fact Toast is running every three seconds and it is displaying the text (index) of each button. Since Toast text changes, I am sure it's being fired every three seconds since it changes its text. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello again guys... I guess I understood what you guys said about Toast. However, how can I update every button after three seconds in sequence? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runnable's `run()` method is still looping over **all** buttons, and changing the color on **all** of them during one call to `run()`.

This line:

```
  handlerScan.postDelayed(this, 3000);
```

does not add a **delay** between iterations of the `for` loop.  It only schedules `run()` to be called again, after 3 seconds.  Try this (with **no for loop**).

```
  runnableScan = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

        GridLayout view = Grid;
        Button btn = (Button)view.getChildAt(buttonIndex++);
        if (btn != null) {
           btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
           handlerScan.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
     }
  };
  handlerScan.postDelayed(runnableScan, 3000);
```

You will need to keep track of `buttonIndex` as a member variable in your class:

```
private int buttonIndex;
```

and then initialize it to the index of your first button.  For example, if you set your content view in `onCreate()`, then use:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_name);

      GridLayout view = Grid;
      for (buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < view.getChildCount(); buttonIndex++) {
         View v = view.getChildAt(buttonIndex);
         if (v instanceof Button) {
            // we found the first button, so stop looping
            break;
         }
      }

      handlerScan = new Handler();
```

The way the code I showed you works is that it will change button 1's color to red, then 3 seconds later, change button 2 to red, then 3 seconds later, change button 3 to red.  If you want to start the process over again, simply reset `buttonIndex` back to the index of the first button, after it finishes changing button 3.

Comment: Hello Nate... first of all, thank you for your answer. It makes a lot of sense. I just edited my code to reflect your sugestions. However even so, it seems like my code wait for the three seconds and then, it changes ALL buttons to red. Notice that I have inserted this: handlerScan.postDelayed(this, 3000); inside the loop. Even so, it changes all buttons to red at once. Any ideas? This is driving me mad!!! =P

Comment: You didn't do what I previously suggested. You were still looping over all 3 buttons.  I've modified my answer, to show **exactly** what you should use.

Comment: Hello Nate! Thank you very much! That did the trick! Also, I just learned a little bit more about how handlers work in Android! Thanks!